# st_read() error: NULL pointer returned by GetGeomFieldRef

Tags: r, r-sf

**Problem:**

A `NULL pointer` was returned while reading `ShalePlay_Bakken_Isopach_EIA_08Jan2015.shp` from [this EIA zip file](https://www.eia.gov/maps/map_data/TightOil_ShaleGas_IndividualPlays_Lower48_EIA.zip).

```
library(sf)

tmp_file <- tempfile()
tmp_dir <- tempdir()

zp <- "https://www.eia.gov/maps/map_data/TightOil_ShaleGas_IndividualPlays_Lower48_EIA.zip"

download.file(zp, tmp_file)
unzip(zipfile = tmp_file, exdir = tmp_dir)

fpath <- paste(tmp_dir, "ShalePlay_Bakken_Isopach_EIA_08Jan2015.shp", sep = "\\")
iso <- st_read(fpath)

# > Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, iGeomField -  : 
# > NULL pointer returned by GetGeomFieldRef
```

`?st_read` points toward the [following link](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc41_multiple_geometry_fields) about the OGR model. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

**Question:**

Is there a way to drop null geometries using `st_read()`?

**Work around:**

The following code, using `rgdal::readOGR()` and `sf::st_as_sf()` to convert to class `sf`, worked successfully (with warning).

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)  # devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

iso <- rgdal::readOGR(fpath)

# > Warning message:
# > In rgdal::readOGR(paste(tmp_dir, "ShalePlay_Bakken_Isopach_EIA_08Jan2015.shp",  :
# > Dropping null geometries: 17, 42, 62, 67, 70, 80, 98, 101, 118

iso_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(iso)

ggplot(iso_sf) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem has been solved [here](https://github.com/edzer/sfr/issues/351).